# Use autokey "WinMove" for move chrome (.url) but it doesn't work

Tags: parameters, autohotkey, multiple-monitors, launching-application

Please suggest me about this WinMove command, After I follow the example of WinMov command at Autokey website below. The calulator can run on monitor 2 (I used 2 monitors, both resolution is 1920x1080px)

```
Run, calc.exe
WinWait, Calculator
WinMove, 1921, 0 ;
```

But when I want to use this command with .url file, It can not move windows to 2nd monitor.

This is my command.

```
Run, screen2_autorun.url
WinWait, screen2_autorun
WinMove, 1921, 0 ;
```

Please help me Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the window is "screen2_autorun" and not "screen2_autorun - Google Chrome" ?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Oh, I'm wrong at title, Thanks